# Apache Solr wildchard search not working

Tags: xml, solr, lucene

I am using Solr in version 6.6.0 with Lucene in version 6.6.0.

I would like to create a search box that shows suggestions of hits as I type in the the query.

Here's my approach:

schema (I only have a `managed-schema` file):

```
<copyField source="someField_a" dest="someField_a_wildcard"/>

<field name="someField_at_wildcard" type="wildcard_type" indexed="true" stored="true" />

<fieldType name="wildcard_type" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

`someField_a` is a `dynamic field`:

```
<dynamicField name="*_a" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

When I type something in the input field, I do get results, but not the ones I want:

Let's say `someField_a` is "ABC DE FG.pdf"

I get a result when I type "ABC " but as I go along, the results get messed up and I dont get the documents I want.

How do I configure this correctly?

Comment: what did you get incorrectly as you go along?

Comment: @Mysterion for one thing, it only matches full terms... it matches STRING but not S or STR or anything. And when I type "SO " I get results starting with "SO " but when I go on, e.g when I type "SO 102" I ge results with "SO-102" but not with "SO 102".

Comment: .. exactly which field are you searching against? `somefield_a` or `someField_at_wildcard`? What does the analysis page under admin say for the indexed name and your query?

Comment: @MatsLindh which field should I be querying?

Comment: If you want to use the analysis chain defined for the wildcard type, you'll have to query `someField_at_wildcard`. Any copy operation happens before analysis, so if you're querying `someField_a`, the definition of `text_general` is how the field is processed. Also - to be exact - this isn't really a wildcard search (where the search string has a `*` in it, but will behave similarly)

Comment: Thanks, that was it!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `whitespace` tokenizer. I assume you are doing a lookup of filenames? In that case, tokenization is not desired.

When you combine the `EdgeNGram` filter with the `whitespace` tokenizer, the `EdgeNGram` filter will start creating ngrams for each token.

You may want to make the search for filenames case-insensitive using `solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory` if those are Windows files.

Comment: Well, I would like the search to find somethig for every character that I enter... and not just match full names

Comment: Okay, you should query on the field that uses the field type. In this case that is `someField_at_wildcard`. I still think you do not need to tokenize though if you want to have literal matching and the order of the characters and tokens matter.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the information! I was was indeed querying on the wrong field.